# Comparing data in a report with the record before it in Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have a database that keeps track of Tech's schedules.  I have a report that spits out the schedules grouped by name.

```
 Dane Morris    
                    1/13/2014   2/7/2014    
                2/10/2014   3/1/2014    
                2/27/2014   3/2/2014        
                3/3/2014    3/21/2014   
                3/22/2014   3/22/2014       
                3/24/2014   4/11/2014
```

In the example if you look at Dane Morris there is an overlap in the dates.  He ends one on 3/1/2014 but starts one at 2/27/2014

I was wondering is it possible to check the dates before and if it's more than the date I'm checking Id be able to change the fonts of both of them so I can easily identify if there is a discrepancy in the time line of dates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DLookUp` function to look at next/previous records.

This Microsoft Support article gives some examples

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210504